# Comparator using a double in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, comparator

This code

```
public class MyComparatorWinPCT implements Comparator<Team> {

@Override
public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(o1.rWinPCT > o2.rWinPCT)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if(o1.rWinPCT < o2.rWinPCT)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
 }

}
```

Produces this output.

> Houston Rockets, 1, 0.793
>
> Golden State Warriors, 2, 0.707
>
> Atlanta Hawks, 3, 0.293
>
> Oklahoma City Thunder, 4, 0.585

Here is how the method is invoked.

```
Collections.sort(teams, new MyComparatorWinPCT());
```

Win percentage is being used to compare and it's a double. I've tried every combo of the return statements but can't get it right. I need it in descending order based on win percentage. The highest win percentage first, then so on.

Comment: Did you mean to return `1` if `o1.rWinPCT < o2.rWinPCT` and `0` at the end?

Comment: Please note that you haven't actually asked a question anywhere in your post, so what are you trying to do, what are you seeing your code do, why do you think it's doing that, what did you try to fix it, and how did that not do what you thought it did?

Comment: Also note that the comparator doesn't care if you return -1 or -10000, so a much simpler comparator is simply one line: `return o2.rWinPCT - o1.rWinPCT;`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans but only if there was not the type conflict int / double

Comment: I can't return what you suggested because comparator only works with ints. WinPCT is a double.

Comment: That's true. Easy enough to work around, of course, but it looks like the original problem got a proper answer anyway.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The subtraction approach seems simple enough until you get to edge cases. What about int overflow? Underflow? NaN?

Comment: @yshavit to be fair, at that point you're probably already using `Long.compare` (or `Double.compare`).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That was what I was getting at. :-) Rather than doing the "easy" subtraction approach and then fretting about the edge cases, it's safer and easier to just use those methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may do following changes in your code:

```
public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
    return Double.compare(o1.rWinPCT, o2.rWinPCT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can get rid of the custom comparator using:

```
Collections.sort(teams, Comparator.comparingDouble(Team::getrWinPCT)); // getter required
```

and if the `teams` is a `List` then further to

```
teams.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Team::getrWinPCT));
```

Comment: and if there's no getter, you can still do `comparingDouble(t -> t. rWinPCT)`